# Pegar evento de clique tag <a> quando ele não foi carregado ainda no $(document).ready MVC - RAZOR

Tags: jquery, mvc, razor

Crio dinamicamente na minha View via razor dados que são preenchidos em uma tabela.

Na minha ultima td tenho os seguintes elementos:

```
<td class="row-actions fixed-col"><a name="excFaturamento"><i class="fa fa-times"/></a></td>
```

Esse elemento ainda não foi criado no momento do

```
$(document).ready
```

No meu arquivo .js coloquei da seguinte forma:

```
$('[name="excFaturamento"]').on('click', 'a', function () {
```

Lembrando que a minha tabela é montada via razor com dados que estão dentro de uma viewbag, ou seja a pagina nunca sera carregada antes do document ready.

Porem o mesmo não pega o meu evento de clique. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao stackOverflow. É interessante dá uma lida no tour para entender como funciona o site. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Se ele ainda não foi carregado, logo não existe.

Answer (score 1):

**Este código faz isso que você pediu. Mas..... ele só irá "executar" o comando do `click` após o carregamento da página. Ou seja, só irá executá-lo após ela ser carregada.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#excFaturamento').click(function() {
    alert("clicou");
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="row-actions fixed-col">
        <a id="excFaturamento" name="excFaturamento">Link<i class="fa fa-times" /></a> 
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: É que depende o que você está tentando fazer. Eu fiz meu teste deixando a página lenta e cliquei no botão. "Após" ela ser carregada, ele reconhece o click. Antes disso, "logo [ou antes de a página ser carregada, o botão] não existe." - @Edilson

Comment: dessa forma que você enviou tambem não funciona, o problema que estou usando razor na minha view para montar essa tabela, então tenho que descobrir alguma forma de pegar esse evento de forma dinamica, pois nunca sera montado antes do document ready

Comment: Deixe isso bem claro em seu tópico para que outros também não se confundam, e assim, lhe respondam de forma satisfatória.